# Using Reflection to call a function in a dll is not working

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, ranorex

Here is the code from the dll:

```
  public static bool SendCommand(string command)
    {

        KillTeraTerm();

        try
        {
            SerialPort portToUse = new SerialPort("COM2");

            portToUse.Open();
            portToUse.WriteLine(command);
            portToUse.Close();

            StartTeraTerm();

            return true;

        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }

    }
```

Here is the code I am using to reference the dll:

```
        Assembly loadedDLL = Assembly.LoadFile(@"G:\PRODUCT VALIDATION GROUP\SOFTWARE VALIDATION\Ranorex Support Files\RTSInterface.dll");
        Type rtsObj = loadedDLL.GetType("Oe.RTS.RTSInterface");
        Object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(rtsObj);

        try
        {
            rtsObj.InvokeMember("SendCommand", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public, null, obj, new object[] { "startbutton" });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

I know i am not using the return value yet... just want to know why this isnt working.

### EDIT!!!!

First exception: 
Message = "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation."

Inner Exception Message = "Request failed." '

DeclaringMethod = 'rtsObj.DeclaringMethod' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'

Thanks for your help. First time using reflection so sorry for the choppy code.

### EDIT #2!!!

Stack Trace from VS:
 Saftey Door Simulator.exe!Safety_Door_Simulator.Form1.btnInit_Click(object sender = {Text = "Initialize"}, System.EventArgs e = {X = 56 Y = 10 Button = Left}) Line 46
 C#
  [External Code] 
  Saftey Door Simulator.exe!Safety_Door_Simulator.Program.Main() Line 17 + 0x1d bytes C#
  [External Code]

### EDIT #3

Inner stack trace:

StackTrace = "   at Oe.RTS.RTSInterface.KillTeraTerm()\r\n   at Oe.RTS.RTSInterface.SendCommand(String command)"

Code for KillTeraTerm:

```
   public static void KillTeraTerm()
    {
        if (Process.GetProcessesByName("ttermpro").Length != 0)
        {
            Process[] teraTermProcess = Process.GetProcessesByName("ttermpro");

            foreach (Process p in teraTermProcess)
            {
                p.Kill();
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "Not working"?  Is an exception being thrown, what is the problem?

Comment: Yes an exception is being thrown. Sorry I should be more detailed. Update coming

Comment: Updates with exceptions added.

Comment: A TargetInvocationException is typically thrown by a type initializer (static constructor). If this is the case here, then you're out of luck. You can't use types whose type initializers fail. Can you add a full stack trace of the exception you receive?

Comment: Updated... also I do also have the ability to modify the dll if needed.

Comment: Why do you need to do it using reflection? Just reference the DLL and use its types directly.

Comment: Yes it has been tested without reflectiona nd it works. Reflection needs to be used because this dll cannot be deployed with the application. Nothing I can do about that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do *not* use Assembly.LoadFile(), it loads assemblies without a loading context.  Use LoadFrom() instead.

The exception message is pretty meaningless, not the kind you'd get out the .NET framework code.  You need to look at the stack trace of the *InnerException* to know where it got raised.

Comment: Added inner exception stack trace.

Comment: Well, read the trace.  KillTeraTerm threw an exception.  You're a heckofalot closer to the source code for that method than we are.

Comment: That method works if I call it when I reference it. When I use reflection it doesnt. Is there something else im missing with reflection and a static method calling another static method?

Comment: Did you notice my warning about LoadFile?  Use Debug + Exceptions, tick the Thrown checkbox to get the debugger to stop at the exception.

Comment: Yes i switched it out. Ok so It seems I am getting a "Security Exception" in KillTeraTerm. "Request failed" . The DLL is on a network drive that is mapped. If that helps any.

Comment: Painful.  You need the LoadFrom() overload that accepts Evidence.  Pass AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Evidence.  Something like that.  Moving the DLL would be a lot easier.